# Как отслеживать появление интернет соединения в Android сервисе?

Tags: android, java

Есть задача реализовать отложенную загрузку видеозаписей на сервер в случае отсутствия интернета. Одна из идей: запустить сервис, отслеживать появление соединения и при его наличии начать загрузку файлов. Каким образом реализовать отслеживание соединения? Если иные идеи - буду рад выслушать.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Подпишитесь на `Intent` `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` (посредством реализации `BroadcastReceiver` или регистрации `<receiver>` в `AndroidManifest.xml`).

Ну и ссылочка на [документацию](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).